# Monitor third party HTTP service in Java / Spring

Tags: java, spring, http, monitoring

How should I monitor a HTTP service from within Spring or Java?
It's third party dependency my service critically relies upon.

Currently I would build my health check around a HttpRequest.
Is there any other way to query an HTTP service? A sophiticated ping alternative?

The dependency has no health endpoint, only a basic login screen.
It's a cloud service hosted a a cloud provider.

Comment: Why do you need to monitor it? It sounds like the service isn't yours to begin with.

Comment: So Ops knows who they should call.

Comment: Shouldn't you discuss that with the third party, instead of creating a brittle monitoring system of your own? Especially when you aren't even sure how to create one? Who will the ops call if it's down, you or the third party?

Comment: wow now you gave a negative vote. this is impressive internetism.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to tell if an HTTP service is responsive is to send it an HTTP request.

If the service responds to something else, that might prove that it's running, but not that it's responsive to HTTP requests.

Comment: I know. I should've mentioned that this is the most basic connectivity test. There is a separate integration test that's also represented in the health check.